# Unknown lifecycle phase "High". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

I was getting below logs when I ran my sprint boot project using "mvn clean install" goal.

```
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/87M
18:26:48   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
18:26:48   [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "High". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
18:26:48   [ERROR]
18:26:48   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
18:26:48   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
18:26:48   [ERROR]
18:26:48   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
18:26:48   [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LifecyclePhaseNotFoundException
18:26:48   Process exited with code 1
18:26:48   Publishing artifacts
18:26:48   Surefire report watcher
18:27:01   Process exited with code 1
```

I'm totally clueless here and looking for some solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Please show your pom.xml.

Comment: You are simply calling maven wrong: `lifecycle phase "High". ... `... not as you wrote...

Comment: @khmarbaise - Thanks for responding on the issue.

Now the issue is resolved.

resolution: I was calling this attribute/parameter "Atlantis High" in teamcity  as environment configuration  parameter to invoke a value in application.yaml file in my source code. This causes the issue and removed it parameter in TC configuration. Now build is successful.